# Асинхронна ли работа с DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, асинхронность

Расскажите пожалуйста - работа с DOM происходит асинхронно?
К примеру смотря на этот кода понимаю что тут нет асинхронности  `const btn = document.createElement('button')`

а с этим фрагментом не сильно понятно `body.append(footer)`

Тут вопрос не про саму асинхронность как таковую и работу с DOM!
Вопрос про то как они работают вместе или они не переcекаються (Асинхронность и DOM)? К примеру добавление элемента в DOM.
Расскажите пожалуйста подробнее про это, если про это что-то вообще можно рассказать

Comment: В DOM совсем нет никакой асинхронности

Comment: а DOM события??

Comment: DOM события это просто синхронный вызов синхронных функций по наступллению каких-то событий, это тоже не имеет прямого отношения к асинхронности (хоть и позволяет построить что-то похожее на асинхронную работу в своём коде)

Comment: Наверное, стоит ещё упомянуть, что изменения в DOM происходят синхронно, но отрисовываются на странице уже после того, как текущий стек освободится.

Comment: И кстати ещё насчёт DOM событий: пользуясь возможностью запускать собственные события с помощью `dispatchEvent`, мы можем поставить [простой эксперимент](https://jsfiddle.net/q6sf4Lu0/), который демонстрирует, что обработчики событий запускаются прямо во время работы `dispatchEvent` и этот `dispatchEvent` будет ждать пока все обработчики отработают, то есть никакой асинхронности в механизме событий изначально нет. Что-то похожее на асинхронность появляется только когда DOM-событие связывается с какой-нибудь асинхронной штукой, например ожиданием загрузки чего-нибудь (onload и т.п.)

Comment: @andreymal, в _dispatchEvent_ явно указано, что обработчик синхронный

Comment: Ах да, полистав спецификацию, я вспомнил одну условно асинхронную штуку — MutationObserver сообщает об изменениях DOM не сразу в момент совершения изменения, а попозже (через microtask queue). Хотя и его можно использовать синхронно с помощью метода takeRecords

Comment: И как всегда забыли про [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле такая работа как раз полностью синхронна, в том числе из-за этого во всех популярных фреймворках изменения собирают и применяют "пачками" в определенные отрезки времени